# VueJs 3 - Reactive Render Function using Script Setup and Composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-render-function, vue-options-api

I have a component called x-input that works as following:

```
     <x-input k="name" v-model="r"></x-input>
     <x-input k="name" :modelValue="r"></x-input>
```

This works fine and it is reactive.

How do I create the same functionality using a render function with Composition API and `<script setup>`?

Here is what i am trying but doesn't work:

```
<script setup>
import { h, ref} from 'vue'
const r = ref("test")
const entity =  h(resolveComponent('x-input'), {k: "name",   modelValue: r  }, {})
</script>

<template>
<entity />
</template>
```

Here entity is not reactive.

Comment: @tao Edit: removed the return . That isn't the issue.

Comment: Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar if needed.

Comment: why aren't you usign a `SIngle File Component`? I think it's an easier way than yours, without using `render function`

Comment: @Álvaro doing something way more complicated (i.e, creating forms dynamically) this is just part that isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you define/import your `x-input` component?

If you import it, then you don't need to resolve it.

```
<script setup>
import { h, ref, resolveComponent, } from 'vue'
import xInput from './xInput.vue'
const k = ref("name")
const r = ref("test")
const update = () => {
          k.value = "name new"
          r.value = "test new"
      }

const entity = h('div',
      [ h('p', 'Entity: '),
        h(xInput, {k: k,   modelValue: r  }),
        h('button',  { onClick: () => { update() } }, 'update')
      ])  
</script>

<template>
  <entity />
</template>
```

Here is the working [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to resolve your component. Just use the component itself.

```
h(xInput, {k: k,   modelValue: r  }, {}),
```

`resolveComponent()` is great when you have dynamic component names.
Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75405334/2487565

Here is the working playground

```js
const { createApp, h, ref, resolveComponent  } = Vue;

const xInput = {
  name: 'x-input',
  props: ['k', 'modelValue'],
  template: '<div>k: {{k}}<br/>modelValue: {{modelValue}}<br/></div>' 
}

const Entity = {
  components: {
    xInput
  },
  setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose } ) {
      const r = ref("test")
      const k = ref("name")
      const update = () => {
          k.value = "name new"
          r.value = "test new"
      }
      return () => h('div', 
        [ 
          // You don't need to resolve your component
          h(xInput, {k: k,   modelValue: r  }, {}), 
          h(resolveComponent('x-input'), {k: k,   modelValue: r  }, {}),
          h('button',  { onClick: () => { update() } }, 'update')
        ])
   }
}
const app = createApp({ components: { Entity } })
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.5; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  <entity></entity>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```